# Viewing all Subversion externals

Tags: svn

Is there a way to view all of the externals references used in my Subversion repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`svn propget -R svn:externals`

Comment: Is there a matching command in Tortoise?

Comment: The "properties" command could do it if all the externals are in the same directory.. I can't find a way to tell Tortoise the "recursive" bit (but here I have an old version, maybe newer ones can)

Comment: Does somebody know how the command would look like with `npm node-svn-ultimate`?